# Read XML content of different language from a URL using DocumentBuilder

Tags: java, xml, encoding

I am reading an XML file from a url

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory
        .newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder;
Document document;
document = builder.parse("http://mywebsite.com/someXML.xml");
```

Everything works fine. I could traverse through all the nodes. But the problem comes when there is other language in the XML file (Ex: Japanese). I could not get the content in the specified language. I should probably set the input i am getting to Unicode. Could anyone solve this.

Comment: Does the XML file contains encoding in the header? If not, it is supposed to be utf-8/utf-16.

Comment: What errors are you getting? How are you examining the content to ensure it is Japanese?

Comment: The XML does not contain any encoding in the header. I am not getting any error. I have stored the content in a file and checked it. But i am not getting the actual japanese language content.